CVAE Synthetic Data Distributed Too Narrowly
I have a dataset containing three features, two float features and one categorical feature with 33 categories. (Called Float_A, Float_B and Cat_A here).
I am trying to train a CVAE to generate synthetic data. The data is transformed using the following sklearn transformer:
df=df[["float_A","float_B","categorical_A"]]

transformers=[('float_A',Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='mean',add_indicator=True)),
('scaler',RobustScaler(quantile_range=(5,95)))]),
['float_A']),
('float_B',
Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='mean',add_indicator=True)),
('scaler',MinMaxScaler())]),
['float_B']),
('cats',OneHotEncoder(),categorical_columns)]`

transformer=ColumnTransformer(transformers,remainder='passthrough')

transformed_df=transformer.fit_transform(df)

My second float has a sigmoid activation function and this is declared as so:
Def sample(self,z):
reconstructed=self.decoder(z)
#Apply sigmoid activation to the float feature.
reconstructed[:,self.float_B_idx]=torch.sigmoid(reconstructed[:,self.float_B_idx])
returnreconstructed

Def forward(self,x):
z_mean,z_log_var=torch.chunk(self.encoder(x),2,dim=1)
z=self.reparameterize(z_mean,z_log_var)
reconstructed=self.decoder(z)
#Apply sigmoid activation to the float feature.
reconstructed[:,self.float_B_idx]=torch.sigmoid(reconstructed[:,self.float_B_idx])
return reconstructed,z_mean,z_log_var

Once the CVAE has been trained, (the training and validation loss appear to reduce as they should), I try to generate a random sample using the following:
random_latent_vectors=torch.randn(num_samples,latent_dim)

with torch.no_grad():
gen_df=model.sample(random_latent_vectors).detach().cpu().numpy()

However all of my samples in gen_df are very 'unspread'.
FloatA, FloatB, Cat[0:2]…

[[0.11782782 0.286538 0.646666 0.266387 0.09747571]
[0.0963359 0.29775462 0.58443785 0.29296008 0.1101962]
[0.1300626 0.31274286 0.59086925 0.30710378 0.10169853]
[0.1232817 0.32317564 0.56470346 0.29102385 0.11446829]
[0.13240162 0.28100765 0.6230704 0.29497638 0.08924796]]

Then when I call scaler.inverse_transform on the gen_df I practically get all the same results on each row.
I have tried various things, one of my categories is very dominant (~90%), so have done some class imbalance undersampling using imblearn to make it only 50% dominant, but still get 100% of samples.
I have tried adding more layers and complexity to my CVAE but again has proven futile.
